# Apply custom function to two columns for every row in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data.frame `DF` that looks a little like this

```
category var1 var2 
apples    1    4
bananas   3    3
orange    4    1 
kiwis     2    3
```

I also have created a simple custom function that generates an output based on two parameters:

```
annualize_fte <- function(tenure, amount)
{
    if (tenure==0) return(0)

    if (tenure>12) {
        result = amount
    } else {
        t_factor = 12 / tenure
        result = amount * t_factor
    }
    return(result)
}
```

I'd like to create a third column var3 that is the result of applying `annualize_fte(var1, var2)` to each row.

I've tried the following and have failed:

```
mutate(DF, var3=annualize_fte(var1, var2)) 
apply(DF, 1, annualize_fte, DF$var1, DF$var2)
```

I get errors around unused arguments or errors that condition has length >1.

Comment: `ifelse(x==0, 0, ifelse(x>12, x, y*12/x))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you'd like to try `Vectorize()` to make it so your function can use and return vectors:

```
annualize_fte_v <- Vectorize(annualize_fte)

(DF$var3 <- annualize_fte_v(DF$var1,DF$var2))
#   category var1 var2 var3
# 1   apples    1    4   48
# 2  bananas    3    3   12
# 3   orange    4    1    3
# 4    kiwis    2    3   18
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! That's a pretty neat function, thank you.

Comment: Just to elaborate another way: Multivariate function application is usually handled by `Map` or `mapply`. Here we'd use `mapply(annualize_fte, tenure = DF$var1, amount = DF$var2)` to get the values. `Vectorize` here creates a modified version of `annualize_fte` built on top of `mapply`.